# jquery how to get the value of the array of array from json

Tags: jquery, json

I have this json

```
{
  "default": [
    [
      1325876000000,
      0
    ],
    [
      1325876000000,
      0
    ],
    [
      1325876000000,
      0
    ],
    [
      1325876000000,
      0
    ]
  ],
  "direct": [
    [
      1328196800000,
      0
    ],
    [
      1328196800000,
      100
    ],
    [
      1328196800000,
      0
    ],
    [
      1328196800000,
      0
    ]
  ],
  "Sales": [
    [
      1330517600000,
      0
    ],
    [
      1330517600000,
      0
    ],
    [
      1330517600000,
      90
    ],
    [
      1330517600000,
      0
    ]
  ],
  "Support": [
    [
      1332838400000,
      0
    ],
    [
      1332838400000,
      0
    ],
    [
      1332838400000,
      0
    ],
    [
      1332838400000,
      0
    ]
  ]
}
```

I need to get the value of the of the first array of the last element in that json

in my example I need to get the `1332838400000`

I couldn't do that myself. sorry.

Comment: `data.Support[0][0]`, Assuming `data` as JSON object. http://jsfiddle.net/sfv4J/

Comment: @Satpal Post it as an answer before someone copies you and gets all the glory.

Comment: @Satpal it is not always `Support`. it is a dynamic content

Comment: @Barmar the content is dynamic. so It is not always `Support`

Comment: Objects aren't ordered, there's no "last" element of an object.

Comment: @Barmar isn't there anyway aside from ordering please?

Comment: mydata.Support[3][0]  Assuming mydata as JSON object.

Comment: If you don't know the name, and the ordering isn't reliable, which element do you want to select from?

Comment: @PranaySoni ther is no `support` always. this data is dynamic so sometime we have `support` and another time we have `inbound` and so on

Comment: use `data[Dynamic][0][0]`,here `Dynamic` a variable which can be `Support` or something else

Comment: @Barmar always I need the last element in the json

Comment: I just told you that objects don't have any order. When you parse the JSON into a Javascript object, there's no way to know which element was originally last.

Comment: @Barmar my english is bad. maybe i didn't explain good. what I need is always the number in the array that comes with the last element in the json

Comment: I don't know any way to be clearer, the order isn't preserved when you parse JSON.

Comment: You need to fix the application so it tells you the property name that was last, then you can use `data[lastProperty][0][0]`.

Comment: Parse it as a string, get the name of the "last" property and then parse as JSON.  You can use the name to get the arrays associated with that property.  I don't see why people are getting upset about finding this value when it's in a string - not an object.

Comment: @Barmar i will give you another information. I need always the biggest number in that json. is that work please?

Comment: Is that a different question or the same one?

Comment: @Archer the same one. I need the biggest number. i said that because Baramr told me that it is not possible to answer my qeustion

Comment: It is possible to answer your question, very easily in fact, but that's even easier.

Comment: @Archer do you think that bukko ansewr is correct?

Comment: Barmar's done what I was just doing - that'll give you the highest value in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the highest of the first elements of each of the elements:

```
var max = -Infinity;
for (var key in json) {
    var arr = json[key];
    if (arr[0][0] > max) {
        max = arr[0][0];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer. but first please check the answer of bukko. is it correct?

Comment: See the comment I posted on his answer.

Comment: You need to study the difference between arrays and objects in Javascript.

Comment: That will only get the highest value if it's the first value in each array.  You need to loop each array as well

Comment: but always the array of each item in the json is the same. so i guess this answer is correct for me. i am trying it

Answer (score -1):

```
var json = '{"default":[[1325876000000,0],[1325876000000,0],[1325876000000,0],[1325876000000,0]],"direct":[[1328196800000,0],[1328196800000,100],[1328196800000,0],[1328196800000,0]],"Sales":[[1330517600000,0],[1330517600000,0],[1330517600000,90],[1330517600000,0]],"Support":[[1332838400000,0],[1332838400000,0],[1332838400000,0],[1332838400000,0]]}';

var parser = $.parseJSON(json)

var key = keys(parser)
var len = key.length
var last = key[(len-1)]
alert(parser[last][0][0])
```

Comment: I guess you haven't read the latest comments above, where he says it's not always `Support`.

Comment: it is not always `support` we can't relay on this

Comment: Sorry, when i wrote this answer there been no comments. Added sample without hardcode.